# Query DSL left join query

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I am a newbie in Query DSL. Now i need to write this simple query in Query DSL:

```
select * from parent_msq pm left join child_msg cm on (cm.id = pm.id)
```

I try do like this:

```
QParentMsg qParentMsg = QParentMsg.parentMsg;
QChildMsg qChildMsg = QChildMsg.childMsg;

JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(em);
q.from(qParentMsg).leftJoin(qParentMsg.id, qChildMsg).on(qParentMsg.id.eq(qChildMsg.id));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message(s) are you receiving?

Answer (score 3):

If the relationship between ParentMsg and ChildMsg entities isn't defined, Hibernate Version Prior to Hibernate 5.1 will not allow the join.

if you are using hibernate 5.1 or later, the following will work.

```
q.from(qParentMsg).leftJoin(qChildMsg).on(qParentMsg.id.eq(qChildMsg.id));
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. Work as expected after just hibernate-core update.